# Can you enforce Internet Explorer 6 AcceptLanguage headers with Group Policy?

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

Can the "AcceptLanguage" header that IE sends be specified by a GPO on the client?

The setting I want to push out is,

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International
    <namnlös>   REG_SZ
    AcceptLanguage      REG_SZ  en,sv;q=0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this specific item can be set explicitly through a specific GPO ADM.

You can of course set registry settings through GPO.

Computer Config
-- Policies
-- Windows Settings
-- Security Settings
-- Registry